# Quick question: how to say if i < the max ammount of numbers stored in an array?

Tags: c

I need to catch an array as a pointer *deposit[25] this has been altered in other functions at this point, it is being catched from main. I want to calculate the sum of all values entered in the array, that shouldnt be a problem for me except...how would i stop at the last value?

like if i say

```
void depositSum(float *deposit[25], float *sum)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= (the ammount of numbers that have been entered into deposit[25]); i++ )
}

how would i translate that from pseudocode to actual C???
```

Comment: You would have to either pass the number of entries in the array to the function, or use a special value (NaN, INF) as an indicator that you have reached the end of the array.  BTW, "float *deposit[25]" is an array of 25 pointers to a float, are you sure you don't want "float deposit[25]" or even " float deposit[]"?

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't provide a built-in way to retrieve the value you want, so you have to keep track of it yourself. There's two different ways to do that:

1. As you're filling up `deposit`, keep track of how many slots you filled with another variable, then pass that to `depositSum` too.
2. Choose a sentinel value (one that you'll never actually put in `deposit`, such as 0, -1, Infinity, or NaN). Initialize all of the elements of `deposit` with that value before you start writing to it. Then in `depositSum`, stop looping when the next value is a sentinel (or after reading all 25, in case you overwrite the last one and there is no more sentinel).